# How to choose which collider child to work with, if I have a lot in the same GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, collider

Just to make things clear, **I'm starting** in Unity know...

...and I'm creating an enemy skeleton which has at least four (4) colliders elements inside of it, but I want to detect the damage I'm gonna deal to the Player with just the *"**hitBox** child" collider*.

[image]

I know I can do that by adding a script to the hitBox and using the function "OnTriggerEnter2D", but I wanted to see if I could do all that using only the "Skeleton.cs" script I attached to my skeleton GameObject.

Is there any other function I should know that could help me treat this problem? Maybe an *"OnChildTriggerEnter2D"* or whatever, idk...

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Skeleton : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region Public Variables
    public float attackDistance;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float timer;
    public GameObject hotZone;
    public GameObject triggerArea;
    public float hp_skel;

    [HideInInspector] public Transform target;
    [HideInInspector] public bool inRange; 
    #endregion

    #region Private Variables
    private Animator anim;
    private float distance;
    public bool attackMode;
    private float intTimer;
    #endregion

    void Awake() {
        intTimer = timer;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (inRange)
        {
            EnemyLogic();
        }
    }

    void EnemyLogic()
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

        if(distance > attackDistance)
        {
            Move();
            StopAttack();   
        }
        else if(attackDistance >= distance)
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Idle", 1);
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", true);
        if (!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("attack"))
        {
            Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(target.position.x, transform.position.y);
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        timer = intTimer;
        attackMode = true;

        anim.SetInteger("Idle", 1);
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
    }

    void StopAttack()
    {
        attackMode = false;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }

    
    public void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        if(target.position.x < transform.position.x)
        {
            rotation.y = 180f;
        }
        else
        {
            rotation.y = 0f;
        }
        transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can either use layers and adjust the [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), or use [tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) and [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) .. and if your `Skeleton` object has a `Rigidbody2d` component then all child colliders are basically combined into a collider compound and you could have a single `OnriggerEnter2D` on it .. it would however still react to all child colliders collisions

Comment: when dealing with physics you shouldn't move via `transform.position =` though since this might break any collision detection

Comment: You could use the "damager's" side of code if you don't it create a new script... set a specific tag or layer to your hitBox and check if the bullet or whatever damage type it is, has triggered this object.